# Network Messages when connecting to network

Tags: firefox-os

I recently bought a ZTE Open C. I'm currently using it as a second phone with a foreign SIM card. Cell coverage is not great and the issue I have is that I keep receiving network messages saying what network my phone just connected to. I will switch the cards for a UK one and see if it continues or it's just a roaming thing.

I tried finding a way to disable that but I couldn't find one. Is there any way to do it? I t gets very annoying when you're riding the subway and you can get 50+ messages in less than 20min.

If currently there's not a option to disable it, I would be more than happy to try and contribute to the project and develop that feature.

Comment: may be worth logging a bug for this.  Is the connection dropping a lot?  My guess would be the code for this would be in carrier.js in the settings app. https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/settings/js/carrier.js

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think that's the issue. While at the office are receive any almost no notifications (might receive 1/2 during working hours). During my commute, I know there are spots where I'm without network coverage. Between the office and home I get several notifications. It's a Vodafone Portugal SIM card, so naturally the majority of the notifications are from Vodafone UK.

Comment: what is the actual message of the notification?

Comment: "
Operator message
Grupo Vodafone
"

Comment: yea that looks like an stk command from the resource file: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/system/locales/system.en-US.properties#l510 this is called in https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/system/js/icc.js#l275 and handling messages from the sim card https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/system/js/icc_worker.js#l86.  The event handler is setup here: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/system/js/icc.js#l16

Comment: Exactly that. If there's no option (I haven't found one) to disable it, I think there should be. It can get pretty annoying.

Comment: can you open a bug entry? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: Is the phone rooted?

Comment: I will. No problem. No, the phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation for adding a comment, so i'll add an "answer" with this information: i've opened a bug for this problem (or at least a very simmilar one) and mentioned this SO thread, here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145174

There are also screenshots of the messages. In my case, they're spam from my operator. Whatever the case, there seems to be no option anywhere to change how some of this messages behave.